# Vue Js: How to add serial number column in Vue Data Table Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using `<v-data-table>` component to show data table in in my app. Is there any way to add the serial number column in this data-table. which starts from 1 to length of my articles array.

and it should start from 1 if any article with any id comes to first.

Comment: Usually, table components show what's in a two-dimensional array in your app state. So the answer is to add the serial number to the tabular data you're going to pass to the component, not to somehow add a column to the generated HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, but you can achieve it by adding a computed property and use `.map()` method to add a new property to each items like `sno`, which stands for serial number. You can rename it anything you want.

```
computed: {
   itemsWithSno() {
      return this.desserts.map((d, index) => ({ ...d, sno: index + 1 }))
   }
},
```

Next, just add a new column in header array to map this new property like:

```
{
   text: 'Serial #',
   value: 'sno'
},
```

The value here needs to be exactly same as the new property name `sno` that you have added in the computed property.

Next, just update `v-data-table` `items` prop to use the computed property `itemsWithSno` instead of the original array like:

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="itemsWithSno">
</v-data-table>
```

That's it.

**Working Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  computed: {
    itemsWithSno() {
      return this.desserts.map((d, index) => ({ ...d, sno: index + 1 }))
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'Serial #',
          value: 'sno'
        },
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat'
        }
      ],
      desserts: [{
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0
        }
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="itemsWithSno" class="elevation-1">
        </v-data-table>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Not getting your issue exactly. Can you elaborate it more and create a small demo to show the issue.

Comment: This really worked. Thanks for the solution. Can you also give a suggestion to update the serial number while sorting the table.

Comment: Thank you @suvalakshmi But I am not able to clearly understand what is your new requirement here. Do you mean the serial number should stay the same when the table is sorted? It would be helpful if you could provide additional information about the context and specifics of the problem. Like which column you sorted, and what result you are getting now for serial number and what is your expected result, etc. Thanks!